# How didn't Aang know that Roku & Gyatso trained together?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

It's totally a retcon in ATLA that Gyatso had never told Aang, 'I trained w/ Roku' right?

Imagine [Bruce Pandolfini](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FuJZz_skls) or [Eugene Torre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31-MtiHrehk) never told, respectively, Josh Waitzkin or Wesley So that they knew world chess champion Bobby Fischer.